# Defining ranges in bash for loops didn't work

Tags: bash, for-loop, chroot

I have the following for loop in bash that creates loop devices in a chrooted directory.

```
for var in 0 1 2 3 .. 7
do
    MAKEDEV -d ${CHROOT}/dev -x loop$var
done
```

This didn't work for me as after it creates loop3 it takes .. literally and tries to create loop.. and fails. However according to this  [tutorial](http://www.cyberciti.biz/faq/bash-for-loop/) it should have worked. I got it to work by doing the following:

```
for (( var=0; var<=7; var++ ))
do
    MAKEDEV -d ${CHROOT}/dev -x loop$var
done
```

I still want to know why the for loop I tried first didn't work. Please help.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think you are reading the tutorial too literally.  The turorial *does* say

```
for VARIABLE in 1 2 3 4 5 .. N
```

but taken literally this is not correct bash syntax - I think the author is simply trying to say that for this kind of for loop you need to explicitly list out all values you need to iterate over.  So in your case this would be:

```
for var in 0 1 2 3 4 5 6 7
```

The tutorial also mentions brace expansion, which @glennjackman gives in his answer which is also entirely correct syntax.

Comment: No, `..` *does* work in [brace expansion](https://www.gnu.org/software/bash/manual/html_node/Brace-Expansion.html) - see @glennjackman's answer.

Answer (score 3):

In bash, you can write

```
for var in {0..7}
```

You cannot say

```
end=7
for var in {0..$end}
```

because [brace expansion occurs *before* variable expansion](http://www.gnu.org/software/bash/manual/bashref.html#Shell-Expansions). If you have your range points in variables, you can use a C-style for loop (as you did) or [`seq`](http://man.cx/seq)

```
for var in $(seq 0 $var)
```

Comment: But I didn't use variables in the range.

Comment: You didn't, but someday you will and you will wonder why it doesn't work.