# Loop in UNIX is not working

Tags: bash, unix, ksh

Please tell me what is wrong with the UNIX code below.

```
#!/bin/ksh

 p=10
 for i in $p
 do
  echo $i
 done
```

i am expecting output as

```
1
2
3
.
.
.
```

but the output am getting is just 10
I need for loop not while loop.

Comment: What if you use `for i in $(seq $p)`? I don't know if `seq` exists in `ksh`.

Comment: i have tried but seq is also not working

Comment: Note your `for` is just doing `for i in 10`, and of course just loops on one vale.

Comment: what can be done than ?

Comment: Check @bashophil updated answer, the `for ...` makes it. Also miracle's `while` is a good way.

Comment: You should be using the seq command. or you can use for loop just like the way in c program.

Please see this [link]

  [link]: http://www.cyberciti.biz/tips/how-to-generating-print-range-sequence-of-numbers.html

Comment: @fedorqui: `seq`does not exist in `bash`and it does not exist in `ksh`. It is not a shell builtin but it is a program that exists on Linux systems.

Comment: By the way, that is not UNIX code, it is Korn shell code.  It would be the same regardless of which operating system the Korn shell was running on (e.g. it runs on Windows as well, although not many people use it).

Answer (score 3):

in *ksh*

```
#!/bin/ksh
p=10
i=1
while ((i<=p)); do
  echo $i
  i=$((i+1))
  done
```

or

```
#!/bin/ksh
# with for you can only do this
for i in 1 2 3 4 5 6 7 8 9 10; do
  echo $i
  done
```

in *bash* it works as expected

```
#!/bin/bash
p=10
for (( i=1; i<=p; i++ )); do 
  echo $i
  done
```

there is a Linux command `seq`that can be used for both *ksh* and *bash*. But it is a *Linux* command. So this will not work on *Solaris* or other Unix systems that don't have the progrtam *seq* installed.

```
# on Linux, bash or ksh
p=10
for i in $(seq $p); do 
  echo $i
  done
```

The following uses only shell built-ins and therefore will work for all bash installations (e.g. on Solaris) but not for ksh

```
#!/bin/bash
p=10
for i in `eval echo {1..$p}`; do 
  echo $i
  done
```

This complicated construct is necessary because of [brace expansion occurrs before variable expansion](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/19057874/defining-ranges-in-bash-for-loops-didnt-work/19057921#19057921)

Comment: the problem is that the *for* works as described in the manual.

Answer (score 1):

You have to assign a range. Otherwise the loop can't work. This should do it:

```
#!/bin/ksh

 p=10
 for i in {0..$p}
 do
  echo $i
 done
```

@fedorqui: You are right, I absolutely missed that. When I do stuff like this in Bash (I don't know if it's the same for KornShell), I go like:

```
for ((i=0; i<$p; i++))
```

Comment: No, it does not. See http://stackoverflow.com/a/19057921/1983854 for more info --> "because brace expansion occurs before variable expansion"

Answer (score 0):

in UNIX KSH

```
#!/bin/ksh

while [ ${i:=1} -le 10 ]
 do
  echo "$i"
  let i+=1
 done
```